# Listbox обрезает кнопки по ширине

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Что сделать, чтобы ListBox не обрезал кнопки по ширине?
При том, что применён margin ко всем сторонам.
Я пытался загуглить, но там вопрос был в том, что он обрезал кнопки по высоте, а не по длине.
Нужно, чтобы они все были одинаковой длины.

[image: Скриншот]

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MenuButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Wheat"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

            <Menu Height="23.926" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <MenuItem Header="File">
                    <MenuItem Header="New Project" ></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Open Project" >
                        <MenuItem Header="WinForms"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="WPF" ></MenuItem>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="Exit" ></MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Edit" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="View" ></MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        <Grid Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ListBox x:Name="ButtonList" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}">
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageR}" Width="0.5cm" Height="0.5cm" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=NameR}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Button.Content>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно установить [`HorizontalContentAlignment`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment?view=netframework-4.8) значение `Stretch`.

Для `ListBox`, чтобы растягивать `StackPanel`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ButtonList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

, и для `Button`, чтобы растягивать `Grid`:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

После этого наверное нужно будет поработать со столбцами `Grid`. Например, выровнять картинку по левому краю:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Похожий вопрос на en.SO: [How to get a ListBox ItemTemplate to stretch horizontally the full width of the ListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838828/how-to-get-a-listbox-itemtemplate-to-stretch-horizontally-the-full-width-of-the)